# Custom Google Map overlay?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

How can you use a custom tileset/overlay on a Google map, like was done here:

http://www.philaplace.org

That is pretty cool, and I would like to experiment with this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to do it.  One way is to create a GTileLayer object and implement the getTileURL() to return the URL pointing to your tiles.

But first you'll need an image that's cut properly in the tile format.  For starters, I'd recommend you look at MapTiler: http://www.maptiler.org/  It will cut images for you AND generate a GoogleMap with the overlay.

Comment: Yes, if I understand you correctly. The tiles are cut and stored in a folder structure

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to look at Google's [Overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html) (especially [Custom Overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays)) and [Custom Map Types](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#CustomMapTypes) documentation for Version 3 of their Maps API.