# Building an app that uses android GPS and custom map

Tags: android, android-mapview, locationmanager

Is it possible to create a map application for say a amusement park so you can see a custom map that shows my current location on that custom map.

Am I at least in the ballpark with my logic below?

Use `mapView` to create a new map class

Use `ItemizedOverlay` to overlay my custom map

Use `GeoPoint` to position my custom map overlay correctly on my `mapView`

Use `LocationManager` to get users position and add a market to the current mapView

**Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!**

Answer (score 3):

You could overlay the custom image on the mapview. I found that you could use [maptiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) which I found in a suggestion in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875564/custom-google-map-overlay).

The exact response is:

> There are a couple different ways to do it. One way is to create a
>   GTileLayer object and implement the getTileURL() to return the URL
>   pointing to your tiles.
>
> But first you'll need an image that's cut properly in the tile format.
>   For starters, I'd recommend you look at MapTiler:
>   http://www.maptiler.org/ It will cut images for you AND generate a
>   GoogleMap with the overlay.

Comment: This looks like a great start. Thanks for the link and info.