# How to add custom layer to Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android app in which I am capturing location using Google Maps API v2. I have a large satellite image ( greater than 500 mb ), this image is geo-coded. We need to display this as one of the layers in the Google Maps like Google map has a choice for satellite imagery. How can it be done. As for using tile overlay we need tiles but I have a single image and that to it is very big in size so I cannot use ground overlay also. I am kind of stuck right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of custom layer overlay we add
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question itself that for using tile overlay we need tiles for each zoom level but i have a single large image.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable but you're going to have to do more. You will use [Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay#coordinates) method, but since your file is too big, you'll be needing to cut it in equal dimensions, [256dp for example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay).

To cut your big map file in tiles you'll be using [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.com/). The software will do the cutting for you and will generate the map files. Kudos for this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875564/custom-google-map-overlay) for the additional info.

Comment: I know I need to cut my big image into tiles but I have to implement map tiler inside my app itself so that once I browse or download the image it should render and cut image in various tiles for various zoom levels. But I don't know what should be the approach for cutting the image into tiles.